# ¿Combinar dos eventos en JQuey?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día a toda la comunidad. Soy bastante nuevo en esto del desarrollo web, y al estar haciendo mi pagina se me presento un problema que no se como resolver. 
Estoy tratando de hacer un menú desplegable que cuando se active el evento `mouse-enter` del elemento `.menu-desplegable` se muestre el menú y por el contrario cuando se active el evento `mouse-leave` del mismo elemento, se oculte el menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el problema es que quiero seleccionar las categorías que estarán en un futuro en el `div` azul de abajo(menú). Pero como es obvio al activarse el evento mouse-leave del elemento `.menu-desplegable` se oculta dicho menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta seria, como puedo evitar que se oculte el menú de abajo si le pongo el mouse encima, y que se oculte si tengo el mouse fuera del `div` menú o fuera del elemento `.menu-desplegable`.

Este es el codigo que llevo hasta el momento, solo oculta y muestra el menú al quitar o poner el mouse encima del `.menu-desplegable`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-desplegable").on("mouseenter", function() {    
    $("aside div.contenedor-aside").toggle(500);
  });

  $(".menu-desplegable").on("mouseleave", function() {   
    $("aside div.contenedor-aside").toggle(500);
  });
});
```

La verdad no tengo ni idea como empezar a hacer lo que me falta, así que les agradecería mucho su ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como tienes el html pero podrías conseguir lo que quieres haciendo que el menú desplegable sea hijo del elemento que lo activa, si haces esto el elemento hijo tendría que estar pegado al padre, no puede haber separación entre ellos, aquí tienes un ejemplo de esta posible solución:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-desplegable").on("mouseenter", function() {    
    $(".contenedor-aside").toggle(500);
  });

  $(".menu-desplegable").on("mouseleave", function() {   
    $(".contenedor-aside").toggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-desplegable {background:red;width:200px;height:50px;}
.contenedor-aside {background:blue;width:200px;height:250px;position:absolute;top:50px;display:none;}
ul li {color:white;font-size:24px;cursor:pointer;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-desplegable">
  <div class="contenedor-aside">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfecto, me sirvió mucho gracias, es que tenia fuera el segundo div, por eso nunca funcionaria de esa manera.

Answer (score 1):

En base a lo que compartiste, puedes agregar una validación a tu menú, validando si el mouse entra a las opciones del menú y colocar un `css('display','block')`, te anexo un ejemplo:

```
('#miMenu').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('display','block');
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: lo probare, gracias.